# r - running a script in terminal using cmd batch

Tags: r, command-line-interface

Is there a difference between running an R script using the code

```
bash-3.2$ R --vanilla < filename.R > & filename.txt
```

vs

```
bash-3.2$ R CMD BATCH loc_mult.R loc_mult.txt
```